# Error on findViewById after upgrading to compile sdk version

Tags: android, kotlin, android-8.0-oreo

After upgrading to compile `SDK` version 26, all `findViewById` showing error:

> not enough information to infer parameter T in fun 
>   findViewById(id: Int): T!

Answer (score 15):

This is because as of Android O, we don't need to cast it. There are a few options. Replace:

```
val textInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text) as TextInputLayout
```

With either:

```
val textInput:TextInputLayout = findViewById(R.id.edit_text)
```

Or:

```
val textInput = findViewById<TextInputLayout>(R.id.edit_text)
```

If you want to know what happened under the covers, as of O underlying method changed to

```
public <T extends View> T findViewById(@IdRes int id) {
    return this.getDelegate().findViewById(id);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In pure Java you will have for example

```
TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.textview1);
```

In Kotlin you can go with this

```
val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textview1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you are confusing `java` with `kotlin` , with android studio `3.0` you can use `kotlin` instead of `java` syntax or you can use both as mentioned on [Android official blog](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/05/android-announces-support-for-kotlin.html)

Also read about [`Get Started with Kotlin on Android`](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/get-started.html)

Update : The function signature 
`View findViewById(int id)`

has been upgraded to `<T extends View>T findViewById(int id)` mean it's applying the inference mechanism for return type where `T extends View` mean the View or it's sub-types

Note : So as mentioned initially ,Applying cast still won't generate any error but just a lint **warning** for using unnecessary cast but could be a bug in kotlin type inference but not in java.

Comment: I should clarify, this question was for Kotlin project. With Android O, underlying findViewById method changed so we no longer have to cast it. In java, we no longer need to cast.

Answer (score 0):

It's Kotlin some type expected error fix it

```
val result = findViewById <TextView>(R.id.textView_result) as TextView
val button_sum = findViewById<Button>(R.id.button_sum) as Button
val editText_i1 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.editText_i1) as EditText
```

Comment: Strange "<TextView>" this gives error and "as TextView" solves the error. Naughty Android