# findViewById in kotlin unable to compile

Tags: android, kotlin

New to Kotlin. 
I am trying to create a activity with a member variable holding button object, but compiler gives me error when I try to do findViewById
I tried two ways for doing this but none works.

Note: I am not using Android extension

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461571/error-on-findviewbyid-after-upgrading-to-compile-sdk-version/44461572

Comment: @duggu this is not the same question. I have already mentioned in the question that am I not using android extension. Also correct answer is already given by zsmb13.

Comment: The problem here is actually due to a different issue than what you've submitted as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you declare your property like this:

```
var btn = null
```

... its type [gets inferred to `Nothing?`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44292717/4465208), which makes it so that nothing other than `null` can ever be assigned to it. What you should do instead is the following:

```
var btn: Button? = null
```

You might also want to look into [declaring your Views](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44285703/4465208) in different ways.